# Create symlinks while preserving subfolders tree

Tags: shell, debian, sh, symlink, ln

Let's say I have the following directory hierarchy

```
|/home
|     |/john
|     |     |/app
|     |     |    |/folder1
|     |     |    |        |/data1.dat
|     |     |    |        |/...
|     |     |    |/folder2
|     |     |    |        |/...
|     |     |    |/cfg    
|     |     |    |        |/settings.cfg
|     |     |    |        |/...
|     |     |    |/start.sh
|     |/deer                             <-- I'm here
|     |     |/app
```

I need to symlink (for space reasons) all the files under /home/john/app excluded the files under /home/john/app/cfg (they are customized for each user) in /home/deer/app while preserving the subdirectories tree inside the app folder.

How can I achieve this? I tried already using a combination of `rsync` (to recreate the subfolders tree) and `find` (to list the files without the ones in cfg), however I am having difficulties telling `ln` to create the symlinks inside the correct subfolders.

```
rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" /home/john/app/ app/
find /home/john/app/* -type f -exec ln -s '{}' app/ \; # I'm stuck here
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to link *every* file under '/home/john/app'.  Just link every dir but 'cfg', and every regular file under './app'.

Comment: It's a simplification, in reality I have an another dir 'plugins' under a fourth dir named 'addons' which I wanted to exclude, so to do that I'd have to traverse the hierarchy level by level with maxdepth and that made it even more confusing to me.

Comment: Ah, a 2nd exclusion, in a subdir yet...  I read this after posting an answer that didn't account for that.  Hmm...

Comment: If 'app/addons/plugins' is out too, then also exclude the whole 'addons' directory, as per code in the answer section.  Then process 'addons' seperately, using the same code, suitably modified.  Perhaps a script that generalizes the process would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted in a 'hackish' way by changing the work directory and retrieving relative paths with `find`, here's what I did

```
# Some variables
basedir="/home/john"
currentdir=$(pwd)

# Duplicate directory tree
rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" ${basedir}/app/ app/

# Create links
(cd ${basedir}; find * -type f -path "app/*" -not -path "*/cfg*" -exec ln -s ${basedir}/'{}' ${currentdir}/'{}' \;)
```

The parentheses are there to cancel the effect of `cd`

Still, I welcome any prettier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before (an *ad hoc* copy of the spec in the OP):

```
% tree /home/
/home/
├── deer
│   └── app
└── john
    └── app
        ├── cfg
        │   └── settings.cfg
        ├── folder1
        │   └── data1.dat
        ├── folder2
        └── start.h

8 directories, 3 files
```

Code, with no **rsync**, featuring what **man ln** calls the "2nd form" of **ln** syntax 'ln TARGET' (create a link to TARGET in the current dir); (also **ln *-sr** for relative symlinks):

```
cd /home/deer/app/
find /home/john/app/ -maxdepth 1 -not -path "*/cfg" -not -path "*/app/" -exec ln -sr '{}' \;  ; 
cd - > /dev/null
```

...after:

```
% tree /home/
/home/
├── deer
│   └── app
│       ├── folder1 -> ../../john/app/folder1
│       ├── folder2 -> ../../john/app/folder2
│       └── start.h -> ../../john/app/start.h
└── john
    └── app
        ├── cfg
        │   └── settings.cfg
        ├── folder1
        │   └── data1.dat
        ├── folder2
        └── start.h

9 directories, 4 files
```